# Regular expression findall python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have text which look like that

> {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Recipe","name":"Tartelette aux fraises et rhubarb'curd","recipeCategory":"tarte aux fraises","image":"https://assets.afcdn.com/recipe/20160527/8530_w1024h768c1cx1941cy2911.jpg","datePublished":"2012-10-10T08:48:00+02:00","prepTime":"PT90M","cookTime":"PT15M","totalTime":"PT105M","recipeYield":"4 personnes","recipeIngredient":["250 g de fraises","150 g de farine","45 g de beurre","40 g de sucre","1  oeuf","1 pinc\u00e9e de sel","20 cl de rhubarbe (r\u00e9cup\u00e9r\u00e9 de ma conception de compote)","3  oeufs","75 g de sucre","1 cuill\u00e8re \u00e0 soupe de ma\u00efzena"],"recipeInstructions":[{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Pour 4 tartelettes ( ou une grande tarte mais je pr\u00e9f\u00e8re les tartelettes, la p\u00e2te sabl\u00e9e \u00e9tant difficile \u00e0 couper :)) "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Pr\u00e9parer la p\u00e2te sabl\u00e9e : "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Couper le beurre en petits morceaux."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Mettre tous les ingr\u00e9dients dans un saladier et tout m\u00e9langer \u00e0 la main ( ou au robot) jusqu'\u00e0 former une boule homog\u00e8ne. La r\u00e9server au frais au moins 1h pour pouvoir mieux l'\u00e9taler."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Pendant que la p\u00e2te sabl\u00e9es pose, pr\u00e9parer le rhubarb'curd : "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"M\u00e9langer le sucre avec le jus de rhubarbe sur feu doux, jusqu\u2019\u00e0 ce que le sucre soit fondu. "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"A part, dans un bol (qui pourra aller au bain marie dans l'\u00e9tape suivante), battre la ma\u00efzena avec 1 oeuf. Lorsqu\u2019elle est bien dissoute, incorporer les 2 autres oeufs, toujours en fouettant."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Incorporer ensuite le jus de rhubarbe chaud en fouettant bien, le m\u00e9lange commence \u00e0 \u00e9paissir. Placer le bol au bain marie et faire \u00e9paissir sur feu doux tout en fouettant tr\u00e8s r\u00e9guli\u00e8rement."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Une fois qu\u2019elle est bien \u00e9paisse, transf\u00e9rer dans un autre bol ou saladier pour la refroidir. "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Pendant que le curd refroidit, cuire la p\u00e2te sabl\u00e9e \u00e0 blanc. Etaler la p\u00e2te sabl\u00e9e et la r\u00e9partir dans les 4 moules \u00e0 tartelette (ou dans un grand moule \u00e0 tarte). Puis enfourner entre 10 et 15 min (en fonction de votre four) \u00e0 200\u00b0C (thermostat 6-7)."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Laisser refroidir les fonds une bonne demi heure."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Monter les tartelettes : "},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"- mettre une couche de rhubarb' curd dans les fonds de tarte"},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"- laver et \u00e9queuter les fraises"},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"- les couper en 2 et les disposer sur le rhubarb'curd."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"- conserver au frais avant de servir"}],

In the field RecipeInstructions I need to get everything write after "text": . I never used regular expression and I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: Looks like you need the `json` module

Comment: I get those informations from an HTML page. I can use it even if it's write with HTML tag? @Rakesh

Comment: Than use xml.etree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a json object but doesn't have [] around it to make it an actual list. You should be able to convert it into a Python native list of dictionaries and navigate it:

```
import json

recipe = json.loads('[' + your_text + ']')
steps = [obj["text"] for obj in recipe if obj.get("@type") == "HowToStep"]
```

What worries me though is that unless you truncated your text to post here, this may not be a well formed json. In which case you cannot use the above code and instead use regular expressions like this:

```
import re

regex = r"\"text\":\"([^\"]*)\""
matches = re.findall(regex, your_text)
```

'matches' should now be a list of all the text elements.

Curious about how this regex works? [Here's a simulator](https://regex101.com/r/jTGua9/1)